# how to ON google add status in adMob?

Tags: android, admob

i have created adMob publisherid but i have not get any adds from google and in adMob->sites and apps->myapp(manage settings) Google Ads Status: Off appear like this..my problem is how to "ON" that google ads status.please resolve my problem

Comment: This link may be useful http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1307260&topic=1307248&ctx=topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the beginning:

1. Go to http://www.admob.com/
2. Click **Log In** and then complete your login.
3. Click on **Sites & Apps** tab at the top.
4. Hover over your app, then click **Manage Settings**.
5. Click on the **App Settings** tab.
6. Scroll down, and there is a setting for **Google Ads:**. It should be the 4th thing down.
7. Change it to **Use Google ads and Google certified ad networks to improve fill rate.**
8. Click **Save Settings**, and you're done.

Now this may or may not resolve your problem. You said:

> i have not get any adds from google

I'm guessing that means that you were getting no ads at all, but what you said after that indicated you simply wanted to enable the **AdWords** ads, which is what I described above. There's a good chance that if you still are getting no ads at all, then you either have a code error or no data connection. If the above did not resolve your issue, then you should edit your question with the relevant code from your app, and I'll see what else I can help with.